# How to query on multiple date using TABLE_QUERY() in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to query on these tables using table_query(). How can I query on all the tables with date range from 2017-03-22 to 2017-03-24.
Format of my BQ tables is (auctions_other_YYYYMMDDHHM)
BQ tables are listed below:

> 1.auctions_other_20170322104
>   2.auctions_other_20170322105
>   3.auctions_other_20170323206
>   4.auctions_other_20170323207
>   5.auctions_other_20170324108
>   6.auctions_other_20170324209

**I am using query:**

```
SELECT  * FROM
TABLE_QUERY(chocolate_raw, "table_id contains 'auctions_others_' and
table_id contains '20170322104' and  table_id contains '20170324209'
")
WHERE
  id='f3667fd6-8329-4124-a4a2-737e637a5e7d'
```

**Getting Error:**

> FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitelly consider using BigQuery Standard SQL as Graham suggesting

If for some reason you still are bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL - try below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_QUERY(chocolate_raw, 
  "table_id CONTAINS 'auctions_others_' 
  AND SUBSTR(table_id, 1 + LENGTH('auctions_others_'), 8) 
  BETWEEN '20170322' AND '20170324'")
WHERE id='f3667fd6-8329-4124-a4a2-737e637a5e7d'
```

Similar version in BigQuery Standard SQL will looks like below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `chocolate_raw.auctions_others_*`
WHERE SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 1, 8) BETWEEN '20170322' AND '20170324'    
AND id='f3667fd6-8329-4124-a4a2-737e637a5e7d'
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all use standard SQL (it's easier/neater). Because you have the hour and minute suffixed, it makes it a little trickier, but something like this should work:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `<dataset>.auctions_other_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170322%'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170323%'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170324%'
```

Comment: If there are 9 tables dated from '20170322' to '20170330', I need to add 9 times  _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170322%' OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170323%' OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170324%' OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170325%' ..... OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '20170330%' ??